# CSS hover chrome does not work correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to have the Pinterest style in my page with the use of CSS. It works perfectly in IE10, FF21, Safari5.1.7 and also with the android version of chrome. But it does not work with Chrome28.0.1500.72.

My HTML is the following:

```
    <div id="columns">
    <div class="pin">
        <img src="" alt="objeto1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pin">
        <img src="" alt="objeto2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut e</p>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

An the CSS the following:

```
#columns {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 15px;
column-fill: auto;
}

.pin {
display: inline-block;
background: #FEFEFE;
border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
margin: 0 2px 15px;
-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
-o-column-break-inside:avoid;
-ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
column-break-inside:avoid;
padding: 15px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease;
-o-transition:all .2s ease;
-moz-transition:all .2s ease; 
-ms-transition:all .2s ease; 
transition:all .2s ease; 
}

.pin img {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
padding-bottom: 15px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.pin p {
font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
}
}

#columns:hover .pin:not(:hover) {
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TRYSR/

The problem is that in Chrome when I am hovering a element it works, but when I change to other element this new one starts to blink while I am moving the mouse over it, and if I stop moving the mouse it remains with the 0.4 opacity. But suddenly sometimes in 2 and others in 6 seconds if I stop moving the mouse it works and the element has the 1 opacity.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. How about the surrounding html?

Comment: On my Chromium 30.0.1553.0 it works. Maybe it's a Chrome28.0.1500.72's bug, and given that Chrome has forced auto-updates, it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: This looks like another instance of the long-standing Chrome positioning bug that sometimes happens when using CSS transition animation in conjunction with the opacity property.  I do not know of a fix besides not animating.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see a small movement when you would hover over the larger pic box. I changed the animation from all to background and it looked like it was removed for me:

```
-webkit-transition:background .2s ease;
-o-transition:background .2s ease;
-moz-transition:background .2s ease; 
-ms-transition:background .2s ease; 
transition:background .2s ease;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pertrai1/zKjZw/1/